# Does "CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=x" affect to all compilations made with make?

Tags: compiling

Does "CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=x" variable affects to compilations made with *make*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL` is `make-kpkg` specific as far as I know.

For make, the standard way of doing things is to use the `-j` (aka jobs) argument:

```
make -j8
```

Answer (score 3):

To affect all the make compilations without using the `-j` option you can specify everything on the `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable.
Something like:

```
export MAKEFLAGS="-j4"
```